# SQL Inner join error

Tags: java, sql, javadb

```
SELECT CommitTime 
FROM Logs 
(INNER JOIN SecurityOptions 
    ON SecurityOptions.Name=Logs.SecurityOption) 
WHERE SecurityOption.ID=22
```

This is the sql string I use to grab data from the DB and the ODBC Bridge gives me the next error `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause`.

And if it doesn't give me this error it gives me that `INNER JOIN isn't supported` and sometimes `Syntax Error`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because of the parenthesis. This part `(INNER JOIN SecurityOptions 
ON SecurityOptions.Name=Logs.SecurityOption)` is being evaluated to an unaliased table, which is causing your issue.

Removing the parenthesis should fix it:

```
SELECT CommitTime 
FROM Logs L
INNER JOIN SecurityOptions SO
    ON SO.Name = L.SecurityOption
WHERE SO.ID=22
```

**Edit:**

However, from the names of the columns, it does not seem to me like the JOIN is a valid one. Usually the join is based on Ids - therefore, it could be something like `SO.Id = Logs.SecurityOptionId`.

I think you should use the query designer in MS Access - just pull the tables in and if there are relationships defined, they will show up right away. If they do not show up, then you would have to look at the `INSERTs` to figure out how these two tables are related to each other.

Comment: ok after I've tryed your fixed my error changed to Type mismatch in expression

Comment: @Swine Well, what type is `SecurityOptions.name`, and what type is `Logs.SecurityOption`?

Comment: Yeah I've found out why I had this error, I thought that they were of the same type Access I forgot to check the type

Answer (score -4):

`INNER JOIN` is **NOT** the same as `FULL JOIN`. **DON'T** Try `FULL JOIN`>

Comment: `INNER JOIN` and `FULL JOIN` are very **very** different.

Comment: Full Join returns match if there is match in ether table, Inner join returns match if there is match in both tables.

Comment: Yea that was INNER JOIN and JOIN. Sorry for the mix-up